# ng-include a view with a Controller and with a variable from another Controller

Tags: angularjs

**Setting:**

I have an angular app

I have a table of geographies. And it shows a names and descriptions.

**What I Want:**

I want a small view of geography's details to display if the user clicks on a given geography in the table. This view will contain many more bits of information. It will be controlled by a different controller than the table.

main.html:

```
<div ng-if="displaySingle" ng-controller="GeographyController">
    <div ng-include="'html/geography-detail.html'" ng-controller="GeographyDetailController"></div>
</div>


<tr ng-repeat="geography in geographies" ng-controller="GeographyController">
    <td ng-click="displaySingleFunction(geography.id)">{{geography.name}}</td>
    <td>{{geography.description}}</td>
</tr>
```

The issue here is that when the user clicks on a given row, I need to pass the id from the that row to the `GeographyDetailController`. But the controller for that row is in the GeographyController.

**Question:**

How do I make this line of code:

```
<div ng-include="'html/geography-detail.html'" ng-controller="GeographyDetailController"></div>
```

pass a single ID to the `GeographyDetailController`?

**What I Have:**

Clicking a given row can make my detail view appear and disappear, it just cannot send that view and its controller the ID that I need it to.

**UPDATE 1**

This works if I want to follow a link to the page, but I don't, I want to include this view into a larger view.

```
ui-sref="geographyDetail({uuid:geography.uuid})"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that I see, **GeographyDetailController** is a child controller of **GeographyController** . Then there are several ways to pass the parameter.

1. You can use the $scope or $rootScope event. That is, when user click on the row, you emit event (`$scope.$emit` or `$rootScope.$emit`) from **GeographyController** , pass your id and call `$scope.$on` or `$rootScope.$on` in **GeographyDetailController** to get the id.
2. Or you can do like this: when user click on the row, you add a new field in the $scope (`$scope.myParam = id`) inside the **GeographyController** and get it like this in the **GeographyDetailController** (`$scope.$parent.myParam`).

Personally, I advise you to use the second method.